# Create hotspot in Ubuntu to share a wireless connection

Tags: networking

How do I create a hotspot in Ubuntu so that I can share my wi-fi connection with other devices? The same works in windows then what is the problem in implementing it in Ubuntu.

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: This link explains creating a hotspot when the pc is connected to a wired network. I want to share my wi-fi connection on the pc with other devices.

Comment: Sorry about that! How about this one: https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/07/quick-tip-how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu/

Comment: The tutorial is for 16.04 I'm using 18.04